# Why this code compiled successfully?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface NSObject (Sark)
+(void)foo;
@end

@implementation NSObject (Sark)
@end

// test code
[[NSObject new] foo];
```

I declared a class method 'foo', but I called a instance method 'foo', and the code was build success in Xcode. Why?

Comment: We could tell you if we saw the rest of the code and your build settings.

Comment: And could you change the title to something English?

Comment: Because foo returns void. It returns nothing. And `[NSObject new]`equals `[[NSObject alloc] init]` which returns an instance of class `NSObject`.

Comment: @gnasher729 sorry for my poor english

Comment: @T.Pasichnyk but foo is declared as a class method, not an instance method.